# NSFectchedResultsController's delegate not firing on inserts

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 `NSFectchedResultsController` for 2 Entities which populates the tableView fine.
If I remove an object, it is removed fine.
If I add an object to the first `NSFectchedResultsController`, it works fine, but does not work fine with the second `NSFectchedResultsController`.

The object is being added `NSManagedContext` in the background thread for both entities. The are being updated deleted and inserted on the same background thread for both entities.

So I am really confused to why the insert/update don't work on the second `NSFetchController`.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Each FRC will have a fetch request set to a single entity. The FRC will respond only to changes that affect its particular entity and then only if you have the FRC delegate properly configured.

You need to make sure that the managed object context used by the second FRC (if different from the one used by first FRC) receives the merge notifications from the background thread.

Comment: I am using the same Managed Object Context on both FRC. I think the delegate it properly configure because I get on delete the call is registered fine.

Comment: Are these FRC for two different tableviews?

Comment: it's one tableview with 2 different FRC